# How do I get a PolyModel class name in a django template on Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, django-templates

I'm migrating from db to ndb and in a django template I have test on the PolyModel class, in db it was: 
`{% if myentity.class_name == "ClassName" %}`

In ndb they have renamed the function ._class_name() - with underscore - and this is not allowed in django:

`TemplateSyntaxError: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'myentity._class_name'`

How do I extract the class in the template?

NDB reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/polymodelclass

*Note: A workaround seems to be {% if "ClassName" in myentity.class_ %} but is the optimal way forward.*